# SDN Pox controller: ARP_TYPE, IP_TYPE, but no ICMP_TYPE

Tags: python, openflow, pox

I have a Pox-based SDN application that listens for PacketIns to the controller. I would like to check if a packet to the controller is ICMP. The Pox docs provide an example to [check if a PacketIn is ARP](https://noxrepo.github.io/pox-doc/html/#listening-to-an-event) as shown by the following code.

```
def _handle_PacketIn (self, event):
packet = event.parsed
if packet.type == packet.ARP_TYPE: # packet.ARP_TYPE is const equal to 2054
    # do something neat with the packet
    pass
```

But I cannot use the same logic to check for ICMP messages:

```
def _handle_PacketIn (self, event):
packet = event.parsed
if packet.type == packet.ICMP_TYPE:
    # do something neat with the packet
    pass
```

The latter code returns an error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'ethernet' object has no attribute 'ICMP_TYPE'
```

There is no packet.ICMP_TYPE, which can be seen by checking dir(packet).

The packet.type is equal to a number which represents a protocol, and somewhere in the pox code these numbers are probably neatly laid out besides the protocols they represent - I have no idea where this may be.  For example, I can see that the packet.type of my PacketIn is 2048, but I don't know which protocol that represents or how to find out.

Comment: I am not sure about this but i think this link will help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nox_dev/dQzwOShh4C0.   
To get icmp type try doing something like this.
`tp = packet.icmp()    
if packet.type == tp.type:    
    # do something`

Comment: @Poojan Thanks, I tried tp = packet.icmp() and  got the error message *** AttributeError: 'ethernet' object has no attribute 'icmp'. I don't see how to check if a PacketIn is ICMP from the link.

Comment: I think this link covers it: https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/issues/205. It includes the following quote from MurphyMc "To check if the packet in a POX packet-in handler contains ICMP, the easiest way is to see if .find("icmp") returns something besides None."

Comment: So did it worked?

Comment: @Poojan some ICMP packets are being detected but I think some are passing through undetected. I'll post an update if it gets any clearer.

Comment: Thanks  I have worked little bit with SDN with mininet and RYU controller but pox is new for me so it will be great to know the answer.

Comment: @Poojan yes it is working : ). I've read various bits and pieces about Ryu so I may try it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ICMP TYPE constant. ICMP packets are actually IP packets. Hence the below code will help.

```
def parse_icmp (eth_packet):
    if eth_packet.type == pkt.IP_TYPE:
        ip_packet = eth_packet.payload
        if ip_packet.protocol == pkt.ICMP_PROTOCOL:
            icmp_packet = ip_packet.payload
```